# SQLite Find missing numbers between range (3000-4000)

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I'm looking to find the lowest missing number between 2 numbers.

there may be jumps between 3080 and 3085, etc and all I would need is 3081.
This is for assigning an id to an entry and these entries can be deleted thus the id is too and because we have a limited range we want to make sure we use all the numbers. So if there aren't any missing numbers it would have to grab the next available number. if it's full till 3850 then it would need to grab 3851.

They are 0 if they have been deleted rather than null if that helps.

```
SELECT number, user_id
FROM entries
WHERE user_id = '18'
AND number BETWEEN '3000' AND '4000'
```

I'm not sure how to get the lowest available number in this sequence, please help. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  What does `id` have to do with it?

Comment: it is the user_id, I updated it to specify. It is so we know which user updated the table.

Comment: I would not re-use identifiers that were previously assigned in a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a self join:

```
SELECT MIN(e1.number) + 1 num_missing
FROM entries e1
LEFT JOIN entries e2
    ON e2.number = e1.number + 1
WHERE e1.id = 18 AND e1.number BETWEEN 3000 AND 4000 AND
    e2.number IS NULL;
```

The critical condition in the `WHERE` clause is `e2.number IS NULL`, which means that this particular number had no next immediate value in the sequence, i.e. it is the start of a gap.

Comment: I get "unknown column t1.id in where clause" ??

Comment: Sorry...my aliases were off.  Reload the page and it should work.

Comment: ah yes that worked it did get the next available number but not the missing numbers..somehow. I think I cant work with this, thank you!

Comment: @KurtisW In general, your question is a gaps and islands problem.  These are tough to solve in databases like SQLite, which don't support analytic functions.  If you need to find all the gaps/islands, then I recommend opening a new question and tagging with gaps and islands.

Comment: Yeh im going to, cheers. Can only post once every 90 minutes at the moment though. I'd say that's lunch!

Answer (score 0):

If you want next missing number for an `id`, then:

```
select e.id, e.number + 1
from entries e
where not exists (select 1
                  from entries e2
                  where e2.id = e.id and e2.number = e.number + 1
                 );
```

If you want this for a particular `id`, then add `id = 18` to the outer `where` clause.